# How to obey contract of equals() when deriving from abstract class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

In his book *Effective Java*, Joshua Bloch writes about the pitfalls that occur with the contract of `equals()` when derived classes add additional fields to the check. Normally, this would break the symmetry, but Bloch states that "you *can* add a value component to a subclass of an *abstract* class without violating the equals contract".

Obviously this is true because there can be no instances of the abstract class, so there is no symmetry to violate. But what about other subclasses? I wrote this example, intentionally omitting hashcode implementations and null-checks to keep the code short:

```java
public abstract class Vehicle {

    private final String color;

    public Vehicle(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Vehicle)) return false;

        Vehicle that = (Vehicle) o;

        return color.equals(that.color);
    }

}

public class Bicycle extends Vehicle {

    public Bicycle(String color) {
        super(color);
    }

}

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private final String model;

    public Car(String color, String model) {
        super(color);
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Car)) return false;

        Car that = (Car) o;

        return getColor().equals(that.getColor()) && model.equals(that.model);
    }

}
```

When I create one instance of each class with the same color string, the symmetry of `equals()` is broken:

```java
Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("blue");
Car car = new Car("blue", "Mercedes");

bicycle.equals(car) <- true
car.equals(bicycle) <- false
```

I am unsure on how to handle this the best way. Declare `equals()` as abstract in the abstract class to enforce an implementation in the subclasses? But the same effect could be achieved by not declaring `equals ()` at all in the abstract class.

Comment: What happens if `o` is an instance of `Bicycle` in `o instanceof Car`?

Comment: This would be false. The problem is the other direction, when a `Car` instance is checked in the `equals()` method of the abstract super class.

Comment: what do you mean with `When I create one instance of each class with the same color string, the symmetry of equals() is broken.`

Comment: @StephanWindmüller you are right, but an abstract class may not have an instance.  One could use `this.getClass().isInstance()` to do this, but every class should implement its own `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Comment: @wero I added an example to the original question.

Comment: @Hannes The statement that "every class should implement its own `equals` and `hashcode` methods" does not work well with inheritance as explained by Bloch in the mentioned book. Adding new fields breaks the symmetry if they are used in `equals` or `hashcode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's equals contract gets especially spotty in situations like this, and in the end it all becomes a matter of the programmer's preferences and needs. I remember reaching this very same issue and I came across [this article](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html), which goes over several possibilities and issues when considering the equals contract with Java. It basically ends up saying there's no way to properly do it without breaking the Java equals contract.

When dealing with *abstract* classes, my personal preference is to not give the abstract class an equals method at all. It doesn't make sense. You can't have two objects of an abstract type; how should you compare them? Instead, I give each subclass its own equals, and the runtime handles the rest whenever `equals()` is called. And overall, the solution presented in the article that I most often follow is the "only objects of the exact same class may be compared", which seems the most sensible to me.

Comment: Is the restriction of "exact same class" really the way most programmers would expect a class to behave? I am unsure about this. For example, take `java.sql.Date`. It inherits from `java.util.Date` without overriding `equals()`. As long as they refer to the same point in time, they are regarded as equal.

Comment: And there's the tricky part, @StephanWindmüller. Using equals, you have to have some flexibility. It is incredibly difficult to 100% enact the equals contract with a subclass override without messing with some rules. In cases like the date case, I wouldn't override, because they mean the same thing in different ways. But for other things, where the subclass has any key differences from the parent, I use only-same-type equals.

Comment: But if the developer of `java.util.Date` has chosen an `equals()` implementation using `getClass()`, it would not have been possible to create a subclass with the current behavior. To sum it up, the answer to my question seems to be "it depends". Your answer is as near to this as it might get, so I marked it as the correct one.

Comment: It depends it always the right answer. Note that if you're developing a framework or a standard library your choices will be quite different compared to developing a single application.

Comment: See jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/inheritance and artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the class object instead of doing an `instanceof` check solves the problem.

```
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
```

Here is the full implementation (generated by Eclipse):

```
public class Vehicle {

    // ...    

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Vehicle other = (Vehicle) obj;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Car other = (Car) obj;
        if (model == null) {
            if (other.model != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!model.equals(other.model)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Both checks in your example will then yield `false`.

Comment: The equals method should first check whether both the object are of same type, instead of calling the `super.equals(obj)` before that. It will call the super class equals() method unnecessarily when two object are not even of same type.

Comment: With using `getClass()`, you only shift the problem: Imagine another subclass of `Car`, it would never be able to be equal to `Car` because it is not the same class. Also your generated code does not honor the fact the Vehicle is abstract.

Comment: @StephanWindmüller that depends on your use-case and opinion of equals. When using frameworks such as Hibernate that create proxy subclasses it might be necessary. Apart from that I think it's not intuitive if two objects are equals but of different type.

Comment: @YoungHobbit the code is generated by Eclipse. In fact, the second check  of `getClass() != obj.getClass()` would not be necessary at all. But the code generator is not as smart as you and me. Nevertheless, generating code such as equals and hashCode is less error-prone than writing it by hand. There are some projects out there that try to automate this all together.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry of the `equals()` got broken mainly, because `Bicycle` class is a subclass and it is dependent on the super class `(Vehicle)` for it's own equality. If you define the `equals()` method for each sub class then you will not encounter this issue.

Here is the `equals()` implementation for each of the class. (Only `Bicycle` `equals()` is added, other implementations are same but simplified.)

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
....
      @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Vehicle)) return false;
    Vehicle that = (Vehicle) o;
    return color.equals(that.color);
  }
}

public class Bicycle extends Vehicle {
...
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Bicycle)) return false;
    Bicycle that = (Bicycle) o;
    return super.getColor().equals(that.getColor());
  }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
...
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Car)) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    Car car = (Car) o;
    return model.equals(car.model);
  }
}

// This is main class for testing the above functionality.

class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("blue");
    Car car = new Car("blue", "Mercedes");

    System.out.println(bicycle.equals(car));   -> false
    System.out.println(car.equals(bicycle));   -> false
  }
}
```

---

**OR** you should use the `object.getClass()` instead of `instanceof` operator in your super class implementation as suggested by @FranzBecker. The sub classes can still use the `instanceOf` operator without any issue.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
...
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if ((this.getClass() !=  o.getClass())) return false;
    Vehicle that = (Vehicle) o;
    return color.equals(that.color);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure about the last part of your answer. Does the usage of `getClass()` in the abstract class make any sense? I am not able to create an object of this class.

Comment: @StephanWindmüller You are right. But the thing is sub class (e.g. `Bicycle`) us dependent on the super class (`Vehicle`) for it equality. That is the only reason. As I mentioned in the answer, If you define the `equals()` for each sub class then it is not required. Also notice that, sub class equals is calling the super class `equals()` for inherited member variables, other wise they need to be handled in the each implementations.

Comment: @StephanWindmüller calling `getClass()` in an abstract class will return the class object of the concrete instance. So if it's a `Bicycle` the code in the method call of the abstract class will return `Bicycle.class` and not `Vehicle.class`.

Comment: @FranzBecker I know, so checking `getClass()` in `Vehicle` as shown in the answer above does not make any sense.

Comment: @StephanWindmüller as the other classes don't call `super.equals` it doesn't. You are right :)

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` essentially compares the state of the object. When creating your abstract class, you should think about how you want to treat the state of the object.

In your case, your Vehicle has a state of having certain color. Question is: **Do you want all vehicles with the same color treated as equal?** Then make the answer to this question part of the contract of your abstract class.

If you answer **YES**:

Simple enough, just make the equals final.

If you answer **NO**:

You (quite understandably) want your equals to be symmetric. Let's look at the following code:

```
Bicycle bike = new Bicycle("blue");
Car car = new Car("blue", "gtr");
assert car.equals(bike) == bike.equals(car);
```

This will fail with AssertionError, because when calling `bike.equals(car)`, you are comparing by bike's standards. To resolve this, you could implement equals for Bicycle. However, you do not want to be looking at all the classes to make sure someone did not forget to implement equals somewhere.

In this case it is enough to make sure in your abstract parent, that different subclasses return false. This can be done simply by replacing your `if (! (o instanceof P)) return false;` with `if (!getClass().equals(o.getClass())) return false;`. Your symmetry will be preserved.

Comment: Using `getClass()` would complicate things with additional subclasses, like a class that extends `Car`, e.g. `Truck`. A `Truck` would never be able to be equal to a `Car` since it is not the same class.

Comment: It depends how you implement it. For example a `Truck` would be equal if your `Car` implements equals with `instanceof`, which would override the `getClass()` from `Vehicle`. Basically you just need to ask the same question at any level of the class hierarchy.